# How does $d\phi =d\lambda+wd\mu$ define a measure $\phi$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In Rudin's proof of the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym theorem, he states if $\lambda$ is a positive bounded measure and $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure, then $$d\phi =d\lambda+wd\mu$$ defines a measure, where $w\in L^1(\mu)$ and $0<w<1$.

 
My question is: how does that define a measure?

I am aware that $d\bar \mu=wd\mu$ implies that for all measurable, nonnegative functions $g$, $\int gd\bar\mu=\int gwd\mu$. So my first guess was to think that maybe $$d\phi =d\lambda+wd\mu$$ 
implies that for all measurable, nonnegative functions $g$
$$\int gd\phi =\int g(d\lambda+wd\mu)$$ 
But I have no idea what to do with the integral on the right. Do we distribute the integrand over the measures and integrate the sum? Do we replace $wd\mu$ with $d\bar\mu$ and suppose $d\lambda+d\bar\mu=d(\lambda+\bar\mu)$ so that at least for a characteristic function $g=\chi _E$ we get
$$\int gd\phi =\int gd(\lambda+\bar\mu)=(\lambda+\bar\mu)(E)=\lambda(E)+\bar\mu(E)=\int g d\lambda+\int gwd\mu$$ 
I do not know what is the convention or the definition of an integral with respect to $\phi$.

Comment: Yes, you distribute the integral over the measures; similarly, to integrate $g$ against $w d \mu$ is the same as integrating $g w$ against $d \mu$. Everything makes perfect sense here as long as you avoid $\infty - \infty$ type issues.

Comment: $d\lambda$ has assumed to be a bounded measure, and $d\mu$ is $\sigma-$finite, so $\infty-\infty$ shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. Is this distributive property a definition or must it be proven?

Comment: @GuachoPerez It's just the definition of the sum of two "compatible" measures (i.e. two measures that never have $\infty-\infty$ problems when added, so for instance the sum of a finite measure and an arbitrary measure). Strictly speaking that only gives you the property for indicator functions but it transfers up to measurable functions in the usual way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at what Rudin says in his proof (it is due to von Neumann as Rudin mentions).

> [image]

Here is Lemma 6.9 (note the last paragraph)

> [image]

Here is the definition of the sum of two measures:

> [image]

Comment: So we have $d\lambda+wd\mu=d\lambda+d\bar\mu=d(\lambda +\bar\mu)$?

Comment: By definition, yes.

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind the definition is Riesz theorem.

This theorem states, roughly speaking, that every measure is a linear functional and vice versa.

check the wikipedia for more info
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem

The measure $d\lambda+\omega d\mu$ is, as you mentioned, is the measure on $X$ corresponds to the linear functional $f\mapsto\int f d\lambda + \int f\omega d\mu$ by Riesz theorem.